# VRTK Steam VR: Climbing Stairs

Tags: unity-game-engine, steam, virtual-reality, vrtk

I'm playing with VRTK for Steam VR in Unity3d and enjoying it. One thing I want to change is to make it easier to climb stairs. Even in the demo, it's difficult to climb up stairs. You sort of have to lean over the stairs to get the teleport up mechanic to work. In the Decrepit Dungeon prefab, the stairs are even harder to climb because they are a bit higher per stair. Is there a way to set the threshold such that it will more easily climb stairs?

I have already tried out each of the thresholds I can find and changing them around, but no go so far.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried having a sloped collider that covers the stairs rather than rely on the box collider per stair?

Many games do this to cheat climbing things by just providing a hidden sloped collider covering the area.

Comment: Yes. For straight stairs, that will work. I have a spiral stair case that is giving me fits. :-)  I kept thinking there was a setting of some sort of setting I was missing, but I guess that isn't the case. I love the spiral stair case, though... not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

As the above poster stated, having a sloped collision surface will probably provide the best results -- even in terms of user comfort, as "jumping" to climb stairs is one of the major sick-inducing motions in an untuned VR experience.

Alternatively, if you are dead-set on using teleport, you could "auto-ascend" a smooth collision surface, fading-out after a short duration at the beginning, and fading in at the end, to reduce motion sickness induced by the uncontrolled motion.

Comment: I do not know what "auto-ascend" is. Can you give me a link or something? I guess I'm too new to Unity3d to know about it.

Comment: I was wondering if there was some way to use the older cloth system to create a plan that automatically conformed to the surface of the stairs. Putting a plane there works great for straight stairs, but not for circular staircases. So I'm still struggling with that. Of course I could just not use circular staircases, but -- well, circular staircases are cool!